# Laravel 5 User Permissions

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am new to laravel (5.2) and followed this great series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zxmf0n2sC1I&index=34&list=PLwAKR305CRO-Q90J---jXVzbOd4CDRbVx

Can somebody point me into the right direction how to setup the authentication that registered users can only edit / delete their OWN posts.﻿

e.g: Logged in User "A" is not allowed to edit Posts from User B.

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ApiGuard. See more: https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard

Answer (score 1):

If your posts table has an `user_id` then you can check if that user is the same as the logged user. For example:

routes.php

```
Route:get('post/{id}/edit', PostsController@edit);
```

PostsController.php

```
class PostsController extends Controller{
    public function edit($id){
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        if($post->user_id !== Auth::user()->id){
            abort(403);
        }
        return view('posts.edit', $post);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Updated including an index method as requested in the comments.

routes.php

```
Route:get('posts', PostsController@index);
Route:get('post/{id}/edit', PostsController@edit);
```

PostsController.php

```
class PostsController extends Controller{

    public function index(){
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index', $posts);
    }        

    public function edit($id){
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        if($post->user_id !== Auth::user()->id){
            abort(403);
        }
        return view('posts.edit', $post);
    }

}
```

Comment: Great. This works perfectly for edit. However something goes wrong with my index view (where all posts are listed). My Code looks like:   public function index($id)
    {
        //create a var and store all blog posts from DB        
        $posts = Post::findOrFail($id);
        if($posts->id !== Auth::user()->id){
            abort(403, 'Zugriff verweigert');
        }

        return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);
    } And the error message is: "ErrorException in PostController.php line 23:
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PostController::index()"

Comment: By convention, the index method of a resource is used for listing and doesn't have any URL parameters, so you are trying to get an `$id` parameter and Laravel says that this parameter is missing. I will update the answer including an index method.

Answer (score 1):

Great. This works perfectly for edit. However something goes wrong with my index view (where all posts are listed). My Code looks like:

```
public function index($id)
{
    //create a var and store all blog posts from DB        
    $posts = Post::findOrFail($id);
    if($posts->id !== Auth::user()->id){
        abort(403, 'Access denied');
    }

    //return a view and pass in the above var
    return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);

}
```

The error message in my view is: ErrorException in PostController.php line 23:
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PostController::index()

I am not sure what to do with the index($id), where ca I grab the id from?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I your Post has an user_id then you can check if that user is the same as the loggin user.  The code will be

PostController.php

```
    class PostController extends Controller
{
public function getUpdatePost($post_id) {

        $post = Post::find($post_id);
        if($post->user_id !== Auth::user()->id){
            abort(403);
        }
        return view('posts.edit',['post' => $post]);
    }
}
```

and your routes file will be

```
Route::get('/post/{post_id}/edit', [
                'uses' => 'PostController@getUpdatePost',
                'as' => 'post.edit'
        ]);
```